# How to do masked input in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Input mask is not working anymore in Vuetify 2.x. I wonder if there is any solution for making mask for v-input-text? Any idea how I can do it?

Comment: I doubt it is fixable any time soon - https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8192

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Vuetify masks are completely removed starting from version 2.0. The only way to get masks back is to take a look to third-party libraries.

By example, use [v-mask](https://github.com/probil/v-mask) this way:

In your **main.js** you could place:

```
import { VueMaskDirective } from 'v-mask'
Vue.directive('mask', VueMaskDirective);
```

And in your component:

```
...
<v-text-field
  v-model="loginItem.phone"
  v-mask="'(###) ###-####'"
></v-text-field>
...
```

You could also use [vue-the-mask](https://github.com/vuejs-tips/vue-the-mask). This lib is also works, but not maintained by author anymore.

Comment: You really saved my day! Working like charm! =)

Comment: any suggestion fo currency masking.?

Comment: @Sae, maybe [this paragraph](https://github.com/probil/v-mask#text-mask-addons) will help you

Comment: Note that this will modify the actual input value. `'(###) ###-####'` and `1234567890` will give you `(123) 456-7890` instead of the raw number.